# Resume app after call

Tags: ios, phone-call, resume

I am allowing user to call from my app. Is there any way to resume my app back after the call ends?

In know "telprompt" url and "UIWebView" but I don't want to use those because they both pop up to confirm call.

I am looking something automatic like "tel" URL, but I want it to return to my app after the  call.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't possible. I tried custom url scheme too, but it won't work. Have to live with it.

Answer (score 1):

No. Even if you registered a custom url scheme for your app (say, myappname://), the Phone app will not invoke it after the call ends.